# Is the StackExchange HTML 5 video support enabled for The Great Outdoors?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

According to [a meta.stackexchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260734/371198), YouTube/HTML-5 video embedding has been allowed for a few years now.

> All Stack Exchange sites that have either YouTube or SoundCloud embedding enabled now use the respective IFRAME embeds. In light of
>   recent flash-related happenings, we have also re-rendered all affected
>   posts, which means that even old questions and answers that contain an
>   embedded video will now use the HTML5 player.
>
> Bye bye, Flash.

I just tried to embed a YouTube video into [an answer of mine](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/20540/12799), and the video does not show up. Per the above quote, does TGO have videos enabled?

Comment: https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/558/can-we-allow-the-embedding-of-videos-in-answers-questions

Comment: You can do gifs https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/20640/why-would-a-seal-be-flinging-an-octopus-around-above-the-water